# How to change PhpStorm SCSS File Watcher Settings to Compile / Export css into different folder

Tags: scss-lint

I have SCSS and CSS folder into a project. I am writing my code into SCSS file which is located into SCSS folder. Now i want to output this code into CSS file and this file location will be CSS folder.

[My project folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wi61.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

|-CSS

|-SCSS

Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css Working directory: $FileDir$ Output paths to refresh: $FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

NOTE: add --style compressed to Arguments for minified output